# One page smooth navigation doesn't work correct

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I am busy with creating an one page design. Now I have some issues with the navigation part of the website. I have search around for a code, that jumps to the specific anchor point, when clicking an item in the menu. Also good to known is that I have a fixed header.

I came up with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// An offset to push the content down from the top
var offset = $('#header').outerHeight();

function scrollToAnchor( anchor ) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(anchor).position() - offset });
}

// When you click on an <a> that has a '#'
$('nav#primary-navwrapper a[href^="#"], #sitemap a[href^="#"], .hireme a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (event) {
    // Prevent from default action to intitiate
    // The id of the section we want to go to.
    var id = $(this).attr("href");

    // Our scroll target : the top position of the
    // section that has the id referenced by our href.
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

    console.log(target);

    // The magic...smooth scrollin' goodness.
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:target }, 500);

    // Prevent the page from jumping down to our section.
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;

}); 

/**
 * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
 * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
 * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
 */
var aChildren = $('#primary-navwrapper li').children(); // find the a children of the list items
var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
    var aChild = aChildren[i];
    var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
    aArray.push(ahref);
} // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
        var theID = aArray[i];
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top - offset; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
        var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
        if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass('current');
        } else {
            $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass('current');
        }
    }
});

//now scroll to the anchor when loading page - this was missing
scrollToAnchor(document.location.hash);
});
```

But I have some trouble with this code.
First off, I think this code can much be shorter than now, is that correct?
Second when I am on a landingspage of the website (not the homepage) and I want to go back, the smooth scroll doesn't work. I thought this was the part that was missing:

```
scrollToAnchor(document.location.hash);
```

And third, I get this error in my developer tool :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/5/

Comment: Have you wrapped that in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code });`?

Comment: Yes. I have wrap it in the document ready. That part is missing in my question. I will edit it @enyce12

Comment: Please also provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @enyce12 http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/5/